# How to retain USB connection over orientation change in android?

Tags: java, android, usb, destroy, orientation-changes

Can please someone in this community give me a hint how to keep a USB connection during an orientation change? The app I write uses the USB host mode and is connected to the midi-output of a keyboard. Which entities (USBConfiguration,UsbDeviceConnection, USBdevice, USBEndpoint,..Interface...???) do I have to save into the bundle during onsaveinstancestate() to be able to seemlessly recreate the connection after a screen orientation change?

Comment: Should be easier to use a service.

Comment: What kind of service should that be? How can I get a parcelable or serializable from my UsbDeviceConnection member?